# Figuring out 'Which Constraint' was violated from SQLException

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, unique-constraint

My code can encounter a 'Constraint Violation Exception' (CVE) for a number of different constraints. In order to display a meaningful message to the user and to take specific action I am parsing the `String` returned by `getMessage()`. It works but is ugly and surely not easy to maintain.

I'm wondering if there is a better way? This must be a pretty common scenario; is there a pattern or best practice I could follow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, since you are interesting in which specific constraint failed, whatever you are doing is the only way to go.

I am not sure which database you are talking about, but you might try.. `SQLException.getErrorCode()` and `SQLException.getSQLState()`. These would give you more information depending on the db vendor.

For example, in Oracle,  `SQLException.getErrorCode()` would just tell you a constraint is violated, not necessarily which constraint.

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2005, will try `getErrorCode() & getSQLState()`, as you suggested. Thanks.